# Location service works in emulator but not on real android device

Tags: android

I would like to get location of user, so I have this code:

```
LocationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        // Register the listener with the Location Manager to receive location updates
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, MINIMUM_TIME_BETWEEN_UPDATES,
                MINIMUM_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);

        Log.d("locationManager ", "locationManager ");

        /*
         * try to get last know location
         */
        Location location = locationManager
                .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    this.location=location;
```

}

and than I send geot fix:

```
geo fix -122.41914 37.77919
```

it works fine in emulator, but when I try on on real device. it doesn't work, and I see the GPS icon blinking on device.
Notice: GPS is enabled on device.

Comment: maybe you don't have gps signal on your device..? did you set the permission in your Manifest?

Comment: You mean: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" >

Comment: you should probably also add `ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION`

Comment: I myself block all location access and disabled location services by Google on my Android. This may be why on real Androids you get some errors. Location is not a right, but a privilege.